# Position Span above text in paragraph

Tags: html, css

I try to place some text above text like this (used in music):

```
     Am          E  
This is a new sentence  
     G            C  
This is another sentence
```

but I don't want to use spaces!
Currently  I have this:

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Test test test <span>Em</span>test test</p>
  <p>Test <span>Am</span>test test test test</p>
  <p>Test test test test <span>Am</span>test</p>
  <p><span>Am</span>Test test test test test</p>
</div>
```

That works but only if I don't touch anything (font-size...) because the bottom value is the same that the font-size value.

I would like to have the same result but without that constraint.

Can you help me please!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `top: -1em;` to move the `<span>` up by it's own font size, since EM is relative to the current element's `font-size`:

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Test test test <span>Em</span>test test</p>
  <p>Test <span>Am</span>test test test test</p>
  <p>Test test test test <span>Am</span>test</p>
  <p><span>Am</span>Test test test test test</p>
</div>
```

To preserve the correct vertical position when the text wraps, I would also suggest displaying the text in a pseudo element, which is positioned in the relation to the text wrapped by the`span`, and not the paragraph itself.

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 100px;
}

span {
  position: relative;
}

span::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.5em;
  color: red;
  font-size: 0.4em;
  content: attr(data-text);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Test test test <span data-text="Em">test</span> test</p>
  <p>Test <span data-text="Am">test</span> test test test</p>
  <p>Test test test test <span data-text="Am">test</span></p>
  <p><span data-text="Am">Test</span> test test test test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !  There is just one more thing: the **line height** unfortunately doesn't care about this span. But that's just a really small problem. This code is nice enough for my current use.

Comment: Glad to help. What do you mean by "the line height unfortunately doesn't care about this span"?

Comment: If my span font size is 10px or 100px, the _line height_ doesn't change. So if the font-size of _p_ is 20px and font-size of _span_ is 50px, the text of the span go on the previous _p_

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect !